# How to convey a meaning of 'comfortableness in shopping' in a more concise way or descriptive but meaningful way (not superfluous)?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, portmanteau-words

What I mean of **"comfortableness"** is a combination of these elements:

1. Easy access to the products and services. (also responsive service)
2. Clean environment and atmosphere (the air is healthy and clean as opposed to dank, messy, dirty or filthy).
3. Complete collection of products and services /goods (wares). (thus I don't need to look elsewhere)

Example:

[image]
**Modern brick-and-mortar retail market**

[image]
**Traditional retail market**

The context is for Academics related to a research of what made the traditional market lost its edge against the modern, retail market shopping experience.

I tried "comfortable shopping experience" vs "uncomfortable shopping experience" 
However, I feel that it lacks something.
If you can help by making a more concise phrase or sentence or probably even better, coin a new word/phrase/portmanteau, it's greatly appreciated! I am doing the writing right now and will update it later.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you indicate what other synonyms you've considered and rejected?

Comment: Hmm, maybe pleasantness, complacency, restful, satiety? but all of those words are off for Academics purpose I guess.

Comment: I am about to write 'comfort'.. will this be okay? it's so hard to find a shorter version of 'comfortableness'. Hmm

Comment: Consumer-friendly.

Comment: Also we used to say "designer goods" which contrasts your two photos.

Comment: Which do you think is better, 'customer-friendly' or 'consumer-friendly'? I am conflicted between these terms. I know the difference between the 'user of the product/service' and 'the one who pays for the goods/service', however, if the case is both (they are the customer and consumer, should we just categorize them as customer?) or maybe a client (I feel that this is more like a bank client - high profile customer..) - well, this will be in another discussion though.

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks for your input! I rarely go shopping except for events or occasional party. Is 'designer goods' like an exclusive items or some special limited goods for sale?

Comment: @Mark Beadles How about coziness? or cozy it was ? it was a flash of inspiration this morning..

Comment: Perhaps *curated* or *orderly*.